# Sort divs and save to database with jQuery

Tags: jquery, postgresql, jquery-ui-sortable, ejs

So I have "tasks" loading from PostgreSQL and I want to be able to sort and save them in the order I choose. I can already sort the div's using jQuery sort but the problem is the order does not save on refresh. I am using the database id for each task as the div id so I can remove them just fine too.

How can I save the user sorted list as the new order of the database so it loads correctly ordered according to how I want it when the page is refreshed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what part are you having problems with? Question is fairly broad

Comment: How do you use jQuery to get the id of where the div is placed, I have the id of the object that I am moving but how do you get the id from the div directly above the new location?

Comment: If using jQueryUi sortable it has `toArray()` and `serialize()` methods. Try logging those to console within different event handlers available in the API. Then once you see structure, send to server with ajax

Comment: Would it be something similar to this? console.log("Output to Array " +  ui.item.attr.toArray() );

Comment: even simpler `var sortArray = $(this).sortable( "toArray" );`